# Typescript table delete by id

Tags: typescript, vue.js, axios

I have been using Javascript, but I have started typescript now, and want to delete data from a table. Every time I try to delete data, I get:

> Property 'id' does not exist on type 'never'.

My Code:

```
<template #action>
    <VButton color="danger" raised @click="deleteBrand" >Delete</VButton>
  </template>

var deleteData = ref(null);

function deleteBrand() {
if(deleteData.value !== null)
directoryStore.deleteBrand(deleteData.value.id).then(() => {
  deleteModalActive.value = false;
});
}

deleteBrand(id: number): any {
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    deleteBrand(id).then(() => {
      resolve("deleted");
      this.setBrands()
    }).catch(() => {
      reject('Nor Deleted');
    })
  })
},
```

This is in store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General points of the use of Vue with TypeScript are covered by the [documentation](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html).

Functions like `ref` where output type depends on input type are commonly generics and accept additional type information through generic parameters:

It is:

```
ref<{ id: SomeType } | null>(null);
```

Also `deleteBrand` function isn't workable; it doesn't have a parameter and doesn't return a promise.

Answer (score 1):

A simple working solution is to not initialize the ref with `null` value,

```
let deleteData = ref();
```

or to init that ref with object schema :

```
let deleteData = ref({id:null});
```